# Criando esquema de tabelas com keywords pre definidas

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, estou criando um esquema de tabela que precisa ser bem otimizado, a razão para isso que serão tabelas que terão de 3 a 5 milhões de registros.
A grande preocupação aqui é com relação a busca, neste caso o famoso LIKE %%... não pode nem passar perto, por conta disso no momento de cada inserção, 3 palavras chaves serão criadas com base no campo principal como um nome de algo, exemplo:

Tabela fictícia "cities" apenas para exemplo com o seguintes campos

```
id|name|visibility|key_1|key_2|key_3
```

Então vamos inserir a cidade de "São Paulo" como um registro, neste caso teremos duas palavras chaves que obviamente serão removidos acentos (programaticamente) e tudo minusculo.

```
key_1 = sao
key_2 = paulo
```

Dessa maneira uma busca em uma tabela com milhões de registros seria assim:

```
select name from cities
    where visibility = 1 
        and (
            key_1 = 'sao' or 
            key_1 = 'paulo' or
            key_2 = 'sao' or 
            key_2 = 'paulo'
        );
```

A questão é: será mesmo que assim é mais rápido que Full text ou wildcards LIKE %%? é uma boa prática?

Já vi grandes empresas utilizando esta técnica, no entanto, gostaria da opinião de vocês.

Obrigado desde já!